# Building complex project with Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have an Eclipse project that depends on several other projects from the same workspace. I know hot to create a simple Ant build script for a single independent Java project, but how to tell Ant to integrate all those project into my main JAR file so my dependent program can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ant, the simplest way is to explicitly enumerate those other projects and include them in the jar target. Something like:

```
<path id="all-projects">
    <fileset dir="../my.other.project" includes="**/*class">
</path>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution : `Create a master project and put all the projects into it and have a single build.xml.`

Another option : `Create a master project but leave everything at the same level (do not place project-components inside the project folder) Then arrange your build script to refer to the other projects via relative paths. Note that with some build tools this is not even necessary as they will look at their repository.`

Answer (score 0):

While you can munge together a solution with Ant, [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is a better solution for managing dependencies than Ant. If you don't want to go with a full blown Maven lifecycle management project, you can also look at using a Nexus repository to store your artifacts, and include [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) in your Ant build scripts to perform dependency management.

Ivy or Maven will provide a better, more manageable dependency management strategy which is likely to be easier to integrate into a team than anything you will be able to assemble on your own.